# How to write a statement to check for my user specified exception CustomerNotEnrolledException

Tags: java, arraylist, exception, throws

I previously wrote an entire successful program composed of 7 classes(`Date`, `Address`, `Time`, `Customer`, `Course`, `InClassCourse`, `OnLineCourse`), an interface (`Invoice`) and of course the test class (`CustomerTest`). The interface `Invoice` has a method `createInvoice` which is implemented in the `Customer` class. In the test case, I created 3 new customers, added their respective courses, and then calculated their charges depending on the numbers of courses they are enrolled in, the type of course they are enrolled in and whether the class is an `InClassCourse` or `OnLineCourse`, and finally print out the information a dialogue box. The list of customers and courses are kept in two separate array lists:

```
ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
ArrayList<Course> courseList = new ArrayList<Course>();
```

Using an enhanced for loop, I polymorphically walked through the `customerList` and created the invoice for each customer.
I have now written an additional class `CreateFiles`, containing a new list of customers and courses, that writes customer data to a file **customers.txt** and course data to file **courses.txt**. `CreateFiles` has a method `writeCustomers` and `writeCourses`.

I am new to exceptions and still learning. To modify my program I would like to add a user-specified exception called `CustomerNotEnrolledException`. The `createInvoice` method in the `Customer` class will throw `CustomerNotEnrolledException` if the customer does not have any courses on his list (several of my customers are not enrolled in any courses), and then handle this exception in my test class.

**My question is how do I write the statement in the try block to check to see if a customer is enrolled in any courses, and if not eliminated them.** I need to do this because after I have eliminated the non-enrolled customers, I will add methods `readCustomers`, `readCourses`, and `generateInvoice` in the Test case and use them to read the **customers.txt** file and **courses.txt** file to create customers and add them to `customerList`, as well as, create courses, which would be added to their respective customers.

I already created an exception class called `CustomerNotEnrolledException` that extends exception:

```
  public class CustomerNotEnrolledException extends Exception
  {
      public CustomerNotEnrolledException()
      {
         super("Customer not enrolled");
      }
```

and my original createInvoice method looks like this:

```
    public String createInvoice() 
    {       
            double total;

        if (cType==CustomerType.STUDENT)
            total = 25;
               else if (cType==CustomerType.FACULTY)
            total = 50;
               else if (cType==CustomerType.GOVERNMENT)
            total = 35;
        else
            total = 0;

       for(Course course:this.courseList)
       {
           total += course.calculateCharge(this.cType); 
       }  

           return (String.format("%s\t\t%d\t\t$%.2f", this.name,      
               this.accountNumber,total));    
    }
```

Comment: Instead of describing our code, post the relevant parts of it, and post the method you would like to write with its javadoc describing what it should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, modify your method `createInvoice()` as follows:

```
public String createInvoice() throws CustomerNotEnrolledException {

    if ((this.courseList == null) || (this.courseList.isEmpty())) {
        throw new CustomerNotEnrolledException("Customer does not have any course");
    }

    // rest of your method goes here
}
```

Then, in every class that invokes the `createInvoice()` method, you must surround the invocation with a try block that catches the `CustomerNotEnrolledException`:

```
Customer customer = ...; // get the customer from some place
try {

    // some code here

    customer.createInvoice();

    // more code here

} catch (CustomerNotEnrolledException e) {
    // handle CustomerNotEnrolledException here, maybe show error message?
    System.out.println("Exception creating invoice for customer " + customer.getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
}
```

The idea is that `createInvoice()` throws a `CustomerNotEnrolledException` if it doesn't have any course in his course list. This is just a guessing of what should happen, since I don't know the problem in advance. Moreover, I believe it's your job to implement the logic properly.

As the `createInvoice()` method throws a *checked* exception, in this case `CustomerNotEnrolledException`, the method that calls `createInvoice()` **must** handle the `CustomerNotEnrolledException` exception, either with a `try/catch` block as I've shown in the example, or by declaring that the method throws `CustomerNotEnrolledException` in its signature (like the `createInvoice()` method does).

Comment: Will the try block be where an attempt to enter a customer would be?

Comment: @AnastaciaKong Not necessarily, the try block must surround the call to `createInvoice()`. You can do the surrounding in the very same method that calls `createInvoice()` or do it in the method that calls the method that calls it, or in the method that calls the method that calls the method that calls it, etc. In an extreme case, you can have a try block in your `public static void main()` method, and in the most extreme case of all, you can declare that your `public static void main()` method throws `CustomerNorEnrolledException`.

Comment: the problem I am having understanding here is when you say that the try block must surround the call to createInvoice. I have one call to createInvoice in my original test case which serves the purpose of retrieving each customers calculated invoice. The line of code looks like this :
       for(Customer c:customerList)
              {   
                  output += c.createInvoice() + "\n";
                  System.out.println(c.toString());
    System.out.println(c.getCourseList() + "\n");   
              }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);

Comment: OK, if that's what you're supposed to do, surround all your test case's code with a try block and catch the `CustomerNotEnrolledException` to handle it properly (depends on what you have to do when this exceptional situation occurs). Don't forget to make your methods declare that they throw this exception, so that the exception can reach your main method.

Comment: Ok I forget to tell you one more thing. Im sorry but I'm modifying this program in parts(#1,#2 & #3). #2 was where added the exception and threw it to the main to be handled, but I just looked at the last part of #3 and missed a fundamental part. I am supposed to create a method called generateInvoice in the test case which I did. This method polymorphically creates the invoice to display in my dialog box. The generateInvoice method handles the CustomerNotEnrolled Exception. When this exception is raised it prints a message to the system prompt.

Comment: So you're done! Within `generateInvoice()`, surround its lines with a try block, and in the catch block display the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can extend 'Exception' into a newly created class that looks a little like this.

```
public class CustomerNotEnrolledException extends Exception {

      public CustomerNotEnrolledException(String message) {
           super(message);
      }

      public CustomerNotEnrolledException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
           super(message, throwable);
      }

}
```

Then import this exception into the class you intend on using it in.

Comment: Thanks, I already created this class. I just need to know how to modify my method createInvoice or if I need to create a new method in the main to check to see if the customers are enrolled in any classes.

Comment: Could you provide your createInvoice method and main so that I can see what you mean? You'll just want to use this exception like any other(try - catch).

Comment: Edit your initial post and add this code to it in a code block for readability please.

Comment: Ok I edited it, and placed the question I am trying to get across in bold. Please tell me if you understand better.